# Blender - Three.js - export/import json files

Tags: three.js, blender

I have a .blender file containing exactly one mesh/object (obj01.blender).
I am creating another .blender file containing a more complex scene, let's say containing exactly 5 of these obj01 objects.

I am Appending objects from obj01.blender to my scene, s01.blender with SHIFT+F1 (Append).

I am appending 5 such objects and then slightly changing their location.

When I export this scene, s01.blender using the Three.js exporter, I end up with the s01.js and another **5 files** obj01.001.js -> obj01.005.js for each of the obj1 objects present in the scene.

Even though the obj01.001.js -> obj01.005.js are identical in content, each object in the scene s01.js refers to a different .js geometry file.

Is this the right behaviour or I am missing something?
Is there a way to 'optimize' the export to have **a single file for common geometries**?

Comment: I think I've found a way: 1. Link object (CTRL+ALT+O). 2. Make Proxy 3. Duplicate linked